# How to get all elements by tag?

Tags: python, caching, diskcache

I use [diskcache](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/diskcache/api.html) to persist my data. I save users `cache.add(key=k, value=v, tag="users")`, now i want to get all users by `tag`, but there is no such method.

How i can do this?

I've found only one way to do this:

```
def _get_all(self):
    r = []
    for k in list(self._cache.iterkeys()):
        r.append(self._cache.get(key=k))
```

But this way does not assume tag as argument, so i can not persist in 1 diskcache instance different items and filter them by tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code of [python-diskcache](https://github.com/grantjenks/python-diskcache), the sole purpose of the tag is be used [in an SQLite index](https://github.com/grantjenks/python-diskcache/blob/9bee7b9ff43f2caf6f84fc6bdf1b6d7a695c0fe8/diskcache/core.py#L2034) which is meant to enable [fast cache eviction/culling](https://github.com/grantjenks/python-diskcache/blob/9bee7b9ff43f2caf6f84fc6bdf1b6d7a695c0fe8/diskcache/core.py#L2058) on the basis of a tag value.

The only SQL statement that `tag` is ever used in is in the `.evict()` method.

There is no official API to get cache entries by tag, and the library is not designed to do that. The whole underlying setup of the database and the item-retrieval mechanics are key-centered.

Comment: i switch to TinyDB